# python regex search

Tags: python, regex

I have another question with regex, i want to catch info1,info2 and info3 :

```
>>> a
'|123|blabla bloblo|90'
>>> b
'|123|blabla[[blibli|bloblo]]|90'
>>> re.search('\|(?P<info1>\d+)\|(?P<info2>[^\|]*)\|(?P<info3>\d+)',a).groupdict()
{'info1': '123', 'info3': '90', 'info2': 'blabla bloblo'}
>>> re.search('\|(?P<info1>\d+)\|(?P<info2>[^\|]*)\|(?P<info3>\d+)',b).groupdict()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

I want to use | as a separator, except if it surround by [[ ]] or {{ }}
for b I want :

```
{'info1': '123', 'info3': '90', 'info2': 'blabla[[blibli|bloblo]]'}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Don't use a single regex for this.  It would be illegible even if possible.  Use a regex to split out the surrounded parts first.  You should start considering a lexer if the syntax becomes any more complicated than this.

Comment: do you have any control over this format? because if you can have single char for quoting e.g. instead of [[ and ]] use say `'` or some other char, you can easily parse it using csv module

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you alternative and assuming that you data doesn't contains quote `"` or you can replace it with any other char, here is away to use csv module

```
import csv
import StringIO
data = '|123|blabla|[[blibli|bloblo]]|90'
# assuming data doesn't have quotes, we can convert [[ and ]] to quotes and use csv to parse it
data = data.replace('[[','"').replace(']]','"')
print data
for row in csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data), delimiter='|', quotechar='"'): 
    print row
```

output:

```
|123|blabla|"blibli|bloblo"|90
['', '123', 'blabla', 'blibli|bloblo', '90']
```